# Why Isn't the Designer Updating When I Change These DependencyProperty Values?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have extended [this example for a RadialPanel](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/04/simple-radial-panel-for-wpf-and.html) with `StartPosition` `LayoutDirection` dependency properties:

```
public class RadialPanel : Panel
{
    public RadialPanel()
    {
        StartPosition = StartPosition.Top;
        LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Clockwise;
    }

    public StartPosition StartPosition
    {
        get { return (StartPosition)GetValue(StartPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartPositionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartPositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartPosition", typeof(StartPosition), typeof(RadialPanel), new PropertyMetadata(StartPosition.Top));


    public LayoutDirection LayoutDirection
    {
        get { return (LayoutDirection)GetValue(LayoutDirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LayoutDirectionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutDirectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LayoutDirection", typeof(LayoutDirection), typeof(RadialPanel), new PropertyMetadata(LayoutDirection.Clockwise));

// ... code from cited article
}
```

`StartPosition` and `LayoutDirection` values are enums:

```
public enum StartPosition
{
    Left = 180, Top = 90, Right = 0, Bottom = -90
}

public enum LayoutDirection
{
    Clockwise = -1, CounterClockwise = 1
}
```

The math works, and everything refreshes when I *build* the project, but I thought that using dependency properties would automatically update the designer when I changed the values in the XAML:

```
<local:RadialPanel StartPosition="Top" 
                   LayoutDirection="CounterClockwise" >
```

... but it doesn't.  It updates when I change the Children of the RadialPanel, but that's it.

How do I enable this?

Comment: Yes, project code is enabled... but that was just luck.

Answer (score 2):

By default WPF does not recalculate the layout of controls after every property change. You need to tell the Framework that given property influences layout.

Use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectArrange` instead of `PropertyMetadata` on both properties, and Framework will run Measure/Arrange of your `Panel` after they change.